# can we use jMeter to to test mobile apps with mobile data

Tags: jmeter

I want to test the performance of a mobile app with the mobile data using jMeter is it possible if yes can anybody give the steps to perform it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
Duckduckgo it and you will have a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is not different from web applications, break it down into next steps:

1. Record your test scenario via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder).
2. Add [Virtual Users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
3. Run your test and analyze results.